# Open eclipse svn project in netbeans

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, netbeans

OK my problem is quite simple

Im about to start working with a team of programmers, and we are using a svn repository to store our code, thy files are set up as Eclipse Project as the rest of my team all like eclipse.

However I am die hard netbeans man, I have tried eclipse Iv given it some time but we do not gel as they say.

So my question is there a combination of plugins /hacks that i can use to access a Eclipse Project from an SVN repository inside Netbeans , without corrupting the eclipse project or causing problems for the rest of my team (I would rather suffer eclipse than do this to them)

Many thanks ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As NA pointed out, there is a way to import your Eclipse projects into Netbeans.  However, arguably, you shouldn't be checking in IDE-specific files into your repository unless you can guarantee everybody is using the same IDE.  Otherwise, I would recommend only checking in the source code, resources, and additional libraries and keep the specific files on ignore and have each individual setup their own environment.

Another alternative, is to check in the IDE-specific files in a different folder in the repository so that an individual can grab them if they need them.

Comment: In theory we are all suing eclipse as that that the im the only netbeans man out of the lot, and am now working on it in eclipse. thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

In NetBeans 6.8 under `File > Import Project` there is both `Eclipse Project` and `Resynchronize Eclipse Projects`. I'm guessing this can be used to work together with people using Eclipse.

UPDATE: [How the eclipse import function works](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/import-eclipse.html).

Comment: Would the project file not be changed the next time that the project is saved inside of Netbeans? You would have to go back and forth between importing the project in Eclipse and Netbeans.

Comment: From the updated link it appears that the Eclipse project will be the master project and NetBeans will automatically update its settings if the Eclipse changes are trivial. Otherwise user input is required.

Comment: I tried this first but it does not work, as when eclipse creates an SVN project it use's a slightly different format which Netbeans will not import other wise this might have worked thanks